# Usar LIKE Sobre Campos Concatenados en MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, concat

Tengo una tabla de clientes que posee 6 campos separados de la siguiente manera:

primer_nombre, segundo_nombre, tercer_nombre, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, apellido_casada

Al ejecutar la consulta:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', primer_nombre, segundo_nombre, tercer_nombre, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, apellido_casada) as nombre_completo 
FROM clientes 
WHERE primer_nombre LIKE '%JUAN%';
```

Obtengo una cantidad de mas de 800 registros, pero al intentar ejecutar el LIKE sobre los campos concatenados de esta manera:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', primer_nombre, segundo_nombre, tercer_nombre, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, apellido_casada) as nombre_completo 
FROM clientes 
WHERE CONCAT(primer_nombre, segundo_nombre, tercer_nombre, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, apellido_casada) 
LIKE '%JUAN%';
```

El Resultado son solo 7 registros aproximadamente, el sentido común me indica que los resultados deberían ser mucho mas que 800 cuando se ejecuta el LIKE sobre los campos concatenados ya que el campo segundo_nombre también posee coincidencias con la palabra "%JUAN%" y supongo que también los apellidos.

Estoy usando MariaDB en la versión 10.2.24 sobre CENTOS 7.0

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tenga en cuenta que la instrucción LIKE se cumple por el string resultante de la concatenación no por cada una de las columnas cómo está pensando, Si quiere que se cumpla por cada campo debe hacer condiciones And

Comment: Lo tengo claro, y es precisamente lo que no esta haciendo la consulta, si el resultado de la concatenación fueran 1000 registros con la palabra "JUAN" en cada uno debería encontrar el patrón, esto funciona si hago el LIKE sobre uno de los campos, pero no cuando ya están concatenados.

Comment: Podes armar un fiddle donde podamos reproducir este problema?

Comment: Hola @Noe7sv, creo que pasao algo más de lo que se aprecia en tu código, una manera de depurar sería mostrar uno de los registros que salen en la primera consulta pero no en la segunda, eso debe dar una pista de lo que está pasando, sobre el papel no tiene ninguna lógica, debería mostrar como mínimo los 800 registros de la primera query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola gracias a todos los que comentaron, finalmente di con la respuesta a este problema, tal como lo indicaba @Roberto revise a fondo uno de los registros y me di cuenta que algunas columnas como: tercer_nombre, tercer_apellido son NULL, cuando se intenta concatenar columnas y alguna de ellas es NULL, el resultado es NULL, por lo tanto para resolver este problema es necesario auxiliarse de la función COALESCE()

> La Función COALESCE() devuelve el primer valor NO-NULL en una lista.

Por lo cual para mi ejemplo el código final quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', COALESCE(primer_nombre,""), COALESCE(segundo_nombre,""), COALESCE(tercer_nombre,""), COALESCE(primer_apellido,""), COALESCE(segundo_apellido,""), COALESCE(apellido_casada,"")) as nombre_completo FROM clientes WHERE CONCAT(COALESCE(primer_nombre,""), COALESCE(segundo_nombre,""), COALESCE(tercer_nombre,""), COALESCE(primer_apellido,""), COALESCE(segundo_apellido,""), COALESCE(apellido_casada,"")) LIKE '%JUAN%';
```

Nota: Se debe pasar un String vacío en el segundo parámetro de la función para evitar que retorne NULL.

Gracias.